# ObjectMapper mapping not reading data properly for List<Map>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, objectmapper

I have a `DataResponseDto.json`

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "customRule": {
        "code": null,
        "executionType": "ON_SUCCESS",
        "description": "Description",
        "owners": null,
        "type": "TWO",
        "enabled": true,
        "objectType": "TEST",
        "syncObjectKPIs": null,
        "inactive": false,
        "responsible": null,
        "id": "0AB58A47D3A64B56A6B74DA0E66935DD",
        "embedded": true,
        "value": null,
        "variables": [],
        "kafkaEventName": null,
        "lastChanged": 1530091858490,
        "createPerson": null,
        "externalId": null,
        "groups": null,
        "eventType": "UPDATE",
        "branches": null,
        "executionOrder": null,
        "createDateTime": null,
        "cronExpression": null,
        "udfMetaGroups": null,
        "name": "Sample1",
        "location": null,
        "permissionsType": "USER",
        "udfValues": null,
        "conditions": null,
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "ChecklistInstance",
            "parameters": {
              "templateName": "checklist"
            }
          }
        ],
        "syncStatus": "IN_CLOUD",
        "executionLog": []
      },
      "customRule": {
        "code": null,
        "executionType": "ON_SUCCESS",
        "description": "Description",
        "owners": null,
        "type": "TWO",
        "enabled": true,
        "objectType": "TEST",
        "syncObjectKPIs": null,
        "inactive": false,
        "responsible": null,
        "id": "5033296D138C45C385AC141E1157B4FE",
        "embedded": true,
        "value": null,
        "variables": [],
        "kafkaEventName": null,
        "lastChanged": 1530091858490,
        "createPerson": null,
        "externalId": null,
        "groups": null,
        "eventType": "UPDATE",
        "branches": null,
        "executionOrder": null,
        "createDateTime": null,
        "cronExpression": null,
        "udfMetaGroups": null,
        "name": "Sample2",
        "location": null,
        "permissionsType": "USER",
        "udfValues": null,
        "conditions": null,
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "ChecklistInstance",
            "parameters": {
              "templateName": "checklist"
            }
          }
        ],
        "syncStatus": "IN_CLOUD",
        "executionLog": []
      }
    }],
  "pageSize": 1,
  "currentPage": 0,
  "lastPage": 0,
  "totalObjectCount": 1,
  "truncated": false
}
```

And I have a class to map this JSON file.

```
public class DataResponseDto {
    private List<Map> data;
    private Integer pageSize;
    private Integer currentPage;
    private Integer lastPage;
    private Long totalObjectCount;
    private Boolean truncated;

// getter setter

...
}
```

Now I am using ObjectMapper to parse this JSON into a java class. It retrieved DataResponseDto with only 1 map in data. It should be 2 maps in data.

ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("mock/DataResponseDto.json").getFile());

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DataResponseDto dataResponseDto = mapper.readValue(file, DataResponseDto.class);
List<RuleDto> rules = dataResponseDto.getData().stream().map(m -> mapper.convertValue(m.get("customRule"), RuleDto.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am getting **rules.size() = 1, it should be 2**

Comment: Does it matter that both entries have the key "customRule"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `private List<Map> data;`
Map cannot have duplicate keys, consider using something else such as `MultiKeyMap` from apache commons (`org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiKeyMap`).

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate keys `customRule`. Try to make `customRules` an array with the rules and re-run the code.

Comment: Oh, I see, I won't be able to change datatype/data. Do we have some other alternative

Comment: You could do a workaround by manipulating the string before you parse it into a JSONObject with regular expressions. The specification says it will only keep the last key/value pair and override existing pair.